# How can I get log messages from the LAMP server on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, logging, lamp

How can I get log messages from the LAMP server on Ubuntu 10.04?
Should I install some good program on Ubuntu for that purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `cat` is not a good idea, especially if logs grow large. Instead, try tailing.

```
sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

`tail` will only show the last N lines of a file. If you want to keep monitoring the last lines, use the `-F` command-line option . Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd> to close the monitoring.

```
sudo tail -F /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

To enable the logging, you must do that in the `php.ini` (look for error-logging). AFAIK that is no longer on by default in Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to watch multiple files I'd suggest [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/). It lets you divide the screen and watch multiple files:

[image: multitail in GNOME terminal]

Answer (score 1):

By default, the display of error messages is disabled in Lamp with Ubuntu 10.04 (I think it was enabled before...).
You can read it with the following command :

```
sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error_log
```

or

```
sudo cat /var/log/apache2/access_log
```

I don't know how to re-enable the display of error messages, but it was really useful.

Comment: they are empty, what I should do to enable them?
My main problem that I get 500 error on my server when I going to some page.

Comment: error.log and access.log